# Error con Trying to get property 'catJuzgado' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Quiosco\resources\views\Listado.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy desarrollando la impresión de dos tablas de diferentes años (2019 y 2020) como objetos.
En la tabla 2019 no tengo ningun problema, pero cuando intento copiar el la misma tabla para el año 2020 me brinca el error Trying to get property of non-object. Debo modificar algo en el Foreach?

```
<tbody>
                                    @foreach ($resultados2019 as $resultado)

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{$resultado->distrito->descripcion}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$resultado->expJ2019->catJuzgado->descripcion}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$resultado->expJ2019->catJuzgado->direccion}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$resultado->actor}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$resultado->demandado}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$resultado->expJ2019->periodoExpediente}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
```

Esa es la tabla 2019 que funciona perfectamente, manda la información de los models de ese año. Para la tabla 2020 me sale el error en tres columnas.

```
<tbody>
                                    @foreach ($resultados2020 as $resultado)

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{$resultado->distrito->descripcion}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$resultado->expJ2020->catJuzgado->descripcion}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$resultado->expJ2020->catJuzgado->direccion}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$resultado->actor}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$resultado->demandado}}</td>
                                        <td>{{$resultado->expJ2020->periodoExpediente}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
```

El error esta en

```
<td>{{$resultado->expJ2020->catJuzgado->descripcion}}</td>
<td>{{$resultado->expJ2020->catJuzgado->direccion}}</td>
<td>{{$resultado->expJ2020->periodoExpediente}}</td>
```

El controlador esta así

```
public function listaExpediente() {
    $resultados2019 = Expediente2019::all();
    $resultados2020 = Expediente2020::all();
    $resultados2021 = Expediente2021::all();


    return view('Listado', compact('resultados2019', 'resultados2020', 'resultados2021'));

}
```

Y el modelo Expediente2020 esta así

```
public function expJ2020(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Expedientejuzgado2020::class, 'idExpediente', 'idExpediente');
}

public function distrito(){
    return $this->belongsTo(CatDistrito::class, 'idDistrito',  'idDistrito');
}
```

Ese mismo esta asociado al modelo Expedientejuzgado2020

```
public function catJuzgado(){
    return $this->belongsTo(CatJuzgado::class, 'idJuzgado', 'idJuzgado');
}
public function exp2020(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Expediente2020', 'idExpediente');
}
```

Y mi ruta esta así

```
Route::get('lista/expedientes', [BusquedaController::class, 'listaExpediente'])->name('lista.expedientes');
```

O porque será que me brinca el error?, los models a usar los defino bien, por eso la tabla 2019 si muestra los datos de la consulta, pero en 2020 no pasa lo mismo

Comment: expJ2020 es la función del modelo Expediente2020 para relacionarse con ExpedienteJuzgado2020 mediante el idExpediente que esta en las dos tablas

Answer (score 0):

Te esta avisando que estás tratando de obtener a `catJuzgado` de algo que no es un objeto, por que de hecho `expJ2020` es null y lo es por que tu consulta actual:

```
resultados2020 = Expediente2020::all();
```

Solo te retornará:

- Una colección con todos los objetos de expedientes donde cada uno tendrá la llave foránea que lo vincula con `Expedientejuzgado2020` pero no mas.

Llegados a este punto puedes considerar 3 opciones:

1. Mediante [*eager loading*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) obtener los datos vinculados de esta forma:

   ```
   Expediente2020::with('expJ2020')->get();
   ```

   - De tal manera que el acceso a los datos vinculados sería con el ciclo **`foreach`** que tienes en tu pregunta
2. Si por alguna razón debes *cargar* **después o bajo cierta condición** los datos vinculados, entonces puedes apoyarte de [**`lazy eager loading`**](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)

   ```
   $resultados2020 = Expediente2020::all();

   $resultados2020->load('expJ2020');
   ```
3. O bien un [*`join`*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#joins) regular por medio del *query builder*
4. Algo que me salta de tu pregunta es ¿Estás creando un modelo por cada año de expedientes?, ¿entonces si se acumulan expedientes de 20 años, 20 modelos y así sucesivamente?, creo que ahí tal vez debas revisar de nuevo la *solución* que estás planteando.

Comment: Si tengo un modelo para cada año y de hecho las columnas de las tablas en cada año son las mismas. Por lo que me extraña que no atrape el juzgado como en el primer modelo del 2019.

Comment: Por que te estaría faltando aplicar alguna de las 3 opciones

Comment: Ya esta resuelto, la tabla Expediente2020 contenía un registro de más que no tenia Expedientejuzgado2020.